# Node-Red, LoraWan Actility plattform

Tags: javascript, json, http, request, node-red

im trying to learn how to add a http get request for the Actility plattform in Node red. For now i only recive an error 401 that the authorization bearer is not included.

Setup is done like this:

[image]

I get two codes from the plattform

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxx' 'https://dx-api.thingpark.com/core/latest/api/devices?deviceEUI=xx&healthState=ACTIVE&statistics=true&extendedInfo=true'
```

First is the token bearer.

second is the request url.

```
https://dx-api.thingpark.com/core/latest/api/devices?deviceEUI=xxx&healthState=ACTIVE&statistics=true&extendedInfo=true
```

How can i create a flow that produces the answer correctly?

Thank you.

[function setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVviv.png)

Comment: anybody? all ideas would be helpful.

Comment: It looks like your `http request` node just needs the proper Authorization header to be sent -- please edit your question to include the code inside your `function` node.

Comment: const request = require('request-promise');

request({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer xxx',
  },
  json: true,
  url: 'http://localhost:<PORT>/more-url',
  method: 'POST',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
})
.then(function (result) {
  // do something with result
});
return msg;

Comment: but this give me a new error the request is not working with node red, the request gives me an error "require is not defined" i dont know how to edit the settings js. but how do i add an curl adress correctly? sorry im a bit confused here :(

Comment: sorry edited the question again with at picture.

Comment: EDIT the question to include the function node code, it is unreadable in a comment

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript inside a `function` node is sandboxed (runs in a virtual machine), and so you cannot use some features like "require". However, this is not a problem -- you can add any header information directly to the `msg.headers` object, either in your `function` node or even in a `change` node.

You don't show us what data you are injecting, but according to the `http request` node info, you can pass all of these (optional) fields as input that can become part of the request to the Actility system:

> ```
> msg.url (string)
>     If not configured in the node, this optional property sets the url
>     of the request.
>
> msg.method (string)
>     If not configured in the node, this optional property sets the HTTP
>     method of the request. Must be one of GET, PUT, POST, PATCH or DELETE.
>
> msg.headers (object)
>     Sets the HTTP headers of the request.
>
> msg.cookies (object)
>     If set, can be used to send cookies with the request.
>
> msg.payload
>     Sent as the body of the request.
> ```

Assuming you are injecting the payload data that you want to POST to Actility, you can just add the Auth headers you need using a simple function node that does something like this:

```
msg.method = "POST";
msg.headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer xxx",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
return msg;
```

Or, let's say you were passing the bearer credential string into the function as the payload, and you have a fixed payload to send to Actility -- then your function could look something like this:

```
msg.method = "POST";
msg.headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + msg.payload,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
};
msg.payload = { "foo": "bar" };
return msg;
```

*Note: in order for these injected fields to be used, the `http request` node **cannot** have previously defined their values as part of the node's configuration.*

Comment: Thanks. It works as a charm edited the script without msg.method. it is depreciated in node red and sends an error

Comment: Thanks Steve, now im thinking of the next step that keeps puzzeling me, due to lack of information from actility platform documentation. how to do a request for a specific device with username and password and a specific url. and also with a device eui number...

Comment: I have no idea -- unless the service provides you with some API documentation, the best you can do is polish up your crystal ball...