# Connect Node-Red to Actility LoraWan plattform

Tags: javascript, json, httprequest, node-red

I'm trying to connect Node-Red to the Actility LoraWan plattform.

Connectivity is an LRC-AS Tunnelinterface.

The sample code described in the tunnel-interface is:

[image]

[image]

Anybody have an idea on how to create a flow in Node-Red that connects to the tunnelinterface and listens to the flow from my devices there?

Note: the deviceeui and token are just examples.

Comment: If you can use curl to get what you need, you should be able to create the same request with an `http request` node -- but you will need to set `msg.headers` and `msg.method` to match. Worst case, use an `exec` node to run the curl command directly...

Comment: Please don't post images of text, it makes them totally unsearchable. Also how does this question differ from the earlier one you asked? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108022/node-red-lorawan-actility-plattform

Comment: Thankyou Steve. I will try to do that!!